# Mathematical proof that white noise has zero autocorrelated

Tags: probability-distributions, signal-processing, correlation

I would like to prove, using the definition of autocorrelation, that Gaussian and uniform white noise have zero autocorrelation. I am working on the continuous case (but I think discrete shouldn't be too different).

Using the definition of the autocorrelation of this link shown on equation 9 (https://courses.edx.org/asset-v1:KyotoUx+009x+2T2017+type@asset+block@009x_31.pdf) we have that:

\begin{equation}
\phi_Y(t) = \lim_{T\to \infty} \frac{1}{T} \int_{- \infty}^\infty d\tau Y_T(\tau)Y_T(\tau + t)) 
\end{equation}

We want to prove that $\phi_Y(t) = A^2\delta(t)$.

Let $Y_T(t) = A \xi(t)$ be white noise. If it is uniform white noise I think $\xi(t) = \frac{1}{T}$ for $t \in (-T/2, T/2)$ and zero otherwise. If we substitute this in the definition we would have:
$$\phi_Y(t) = A^2 \lim_{T\to \infty} \frac{1}{T} \int_{- \infty}^\infty d\tau \frac{1}{T^2}  $$
but this is not the $\delta(t)$ function. Where am I wrong? See bottom for a better attempt, using the time representation.

I also tried with Gaussian white noise. Gaussian noise is given by: $Y_T(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(t - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$, if I include this in the definition of autocorrelation we have:

$$\phi_Y(t) = \lim_{T\to \infty} \frac{1}{T \sigma^2 2 \pi} \int_{- \infty}^\infty d\tau  e^{-\frac{(\tau - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{(\tau + t- \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$
which can be re-written as
$$\phi_Y(t) = \lim_{T\to \infty} \frac{1}{T \sigma^2 2 \pi} \int_{- \infty}^\infty d\tau  e^{-\frac{(\tau - \mu)^2}{\sigma^2}} e^{\frac{-t(t + 2\tau - 2\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$
Under some conditions I would expect the $\delta(t)$ function to come up, but I don't see where.

**Edit**
The frequency representation of uniform white noise is a constant probability $\tilde{\xi(\omega)} = p \in (0, 1)$.  However, to obtain the time representation we must take the inverse Fourier transform.

\begin{equation}
Y_T(\tau) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty d\omega e^{-i\omega \tau} Ap = Ap \delta(\tau).
\end{equation}

Now we substitute in the definition of $\phi_Y(t)$ and we get

\begin{equation}
\phi_Y(t) = \lim_{T\to \infty} \frac{1}{T} \int_{- \infty}^\infty d\tau Ap\delta(\tau)Ap\delta(\tau + t)).
\end{equation}
Now, I know that $\int_{- \infty}^\infty d\tau Ap\delta(\tau)Ap\delta(\tau + t)) = (Ap)^2 \delta(t)$. However, I am still confused by the term $\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{1}{T}$ and about the $p$ being introduced (although this might just mean amplitude I guess).

Comment: One issue in the first approach is that you didn't change your limits of integration. Note that your definition has inherent bounds on the domain. Moreover, you're looking at the frequency representation of white noise but your integral is over time. You would need to take the Fourier transform to get the time representation. The time representation should be a sinc. As for the second, you should try actually doing the integral, then take a limit. Here's a hint: take a Fourier transform. Something might be slightly off since you're missing $T$ dependence.

Comment: Thanks! I am a bit confused on why I should change limits of integration? Since I have not done a change of variable. Good point on the frequency/time representation, I'll work on that. For the second, I think there is an extra restriction gaussian noise has to have to be white, which probably introduces the $T$ dependence?

Comment: Made an edit, using your hint. Fourier transform to pass to the time domain. I still think there is something off with the T.